# In function ‘yylex’: 'Variable’ undeclared

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am working with **Lexical Analysis**. For this I am using `Flex` and I fetch following Problems.

## work.l

```
int cnt = 0,num_lines=0,num_chars=0; // Problem here.
%%
[" "]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+      {++cnt;}
\n  {++num_lines; ++num_chars;}
.   {++num_chars;}
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
int main()
{   yyin = freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    yylex();
    printf("%d %d %d\n", cnt, num_lines,num_chars);
    return 0;
}
```

then, I use following command and it work properly and create `lex.yy.c`.

> Rezwans-iMac:laqb-2 rezwan$ flex work.l
>
> ---

then, I use following command.

> Rezwans-iMac:laqb-2 rezwan$ gcc lex.yy.c -o b

and getting following `error`:

```
work.l: In function ‘yylex’:
work.l:3:4: error: ‘cnt’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean int’?
 [" "]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+  {++cnt;}
    ^~~
    int
work.l:3:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
work.l:4:4: error: ‘num_lines’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 \n {++num_lines; ++num_chars;}
    ^~~~~~~~~
work.l:4:17: error: ‘num_chars’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘num_lines’?
 \n {++num_lines; ++num_chars;}
                 ^~~~~~~~~
                 num_lines
work.l: In function ‘main’:
work.l:15:23: error: ‘cnt’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘int’?
  return 0;
                       ^  
                       int
work.l:15:28: error: ‘num_lines’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  return 0;
                            ^        
work.l:15:38: error: ‘num_chars’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘num_lines’?
  return 0;
                                      ^        
                                      num_lines
```

I am not getting above `error`, if I modify `work.l` file like this .

```
    int cnt = 0,num_lines=0,num_chars=0; // then work properly above command.
%%
[" "]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+      {++cnt;}
\n  {++num_lines; ++num_chars;}
.   {++num_chars;}
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
int main()
{   yyin = freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    yylex();
    printf("%d %d %d\n", cnt, num_lines,num_chars);
    return 0;
}
```

That is to say, If I use `1 tab` before this line `int cnt = 0,num_lines=0,num_chars=0;`, it works properly.

**Now I have two question:**

1. Is necessary use `1 tab` before this line `int cnt = 0,num_lines=0,num_chars=0;`? why? explain logically.
2. Is another solution to solve this error ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation about the format of the definitions section?

Comment: Yeah @molbdnilo. But I could not find suchlike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very sure about the tab problem but one explanation is that if you don't place tab and write in the first section something like:

```
int cnt = 0;
```

Then note that in the first section you may also write "shortcuts" like:

```
Digit  [0-9]
```

which is a regular expression that defines what digit is instead of writing all the time `[0-9]` to denote digit.

So when writing `int cnt = 0;` in the first column without using tab is like defining the keyword int (that's probably why the error tells you `did you mean int’?`). So tab is a way to distinguish the two above cases.

> **According to flex** in order to write c/c++ code it needs to be inside: `%{  ... c/c++ code...  %}` so for your example:
>
> ```
> %{
>    int cnt = 0,num_lines=0,num_chars=0;
> %}
> ```

So I thing the best way is to write your c-code inside `%{ %}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice explanation.